# コメントのヘルプにある「批判」という表現はキツくないでしょうか？

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[コメントのヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)に「作成者が投稿を改善するのに役立つ**建設的な批判**を残す」という文章があります。この文章ですが、”**批判**”という表現はちょっと、キツイ表現に思います。"**建設的な指摘**"とか"**建設的な注意**"、"**建設的な意見**"といった表現はいかがでしょうか？

私の周りで、スタック・オーバーフローは質問が批判されるので、質問するのが怖いという人がいました。こういった人達は他のQ&Aサービスを使っています。

スタック・オーバーフローでは注意を出来たり、回答を書き換えたりできることで、より良い記録が残っていく訳で、ここが他のQ&Aサービスよりも素晴らしい点なのですが、「批判されるから...」といった間違った印象でサービスが使われないのは非常に残念です。

この提案は、ほんの些細なことですが、少しでも改善できればと思っています。

Answer (score 12):

あくまでも「[批判](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%89%B9%E5%88%A4-612181)」であって、「非難」や「あら捜し」ではありませんから、辞書的には問題無いとは思います。とはいえ、マイナスのニュアンスを感じ取る人がいることも否定はしません。

「**建設的な指摘**」への言い換えに一票入れたいと思います。

参考までに、[本家SOのヘルプ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)では "criticism" となっており、ここから直訳されたようです。

> Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;

Comment: これいいですね。ご存知だと思いますが、２月から[だれでも当サイトの翻訳を支援できるようになりました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1680/)。もし興味あれば、[当チャットでやりとりしています](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)。（yohjpだけではなく、だれでも大歓迎！英語を知らなくても大丈夫！)

Comment: @jmac 特に反対意見もないようなので適用してもよさそうですが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist やりましょう！

Comment: @unarist ここも変更可能ですか：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%E6%89%B9%E5%88%A4